# How to recreate closed client in Elasticsearch Unit Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, elasticsearch

I have been using **org.elasticsearch.test.ElasticsearchIntegrationTesting** class for testing elasticsearch functionality.

I Use below code to import data into Elasticsearch and to search that data :**

```
  @Test
public void searchData() throws Exception{
   logger.info("searchData : searching data from Elasticsearch");
   try {
       csvImporter.client =  client();
       csvImporter.importData();   // In the importData method after data is imported we close the client

       //In the below line getting Exception and it is inconsistent. Some times works fine

       SearchResponse searchResponse = csvImporter.client.prepareSearch().setQuery(matchAllQuery()).execute().actionGet();
       for (SearchHit searchHit : searchResponse.getHits()){
          logger.info("Source Data >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + searchHit.sourceAsString());
       }
   } finally {
       csvImporter.client.close();
   }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
    org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([86EB1B4AAE1739A5:99315B8D3D924DA1]:0)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:305)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:200)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportIndicesAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportIndicesAdminClient.java:86)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractIndicesAdminClient.deleteTemplate(AbstractIndicesAdminClient.java:687)
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.template.delete.DeleteIndexTemplateRequestBuilder.doExecute(DeleteIndexTemplateRequestBuilder.java:40)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
at org.elasticsearch.test.TestCluster.wipeTemplates(TestCluster.java:177)
at org.elasticsearch.test.TestCluster.wipe(TestCluster.java:76)
at org.elasticsearch.test.ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.beforeInternal(ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.java:292)
at org.elasticsearch.test.ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.before(ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.java:1946)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.invoke(RandomizedRunner.java:1665)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$9.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:898)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$10.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:914)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleSetupTeardownChained$1.evaluate(TestRuleSetupTeardownChained.java:50)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleFieldCacheSanity$1.evaluate(TestRuleFieldCacheSanity.java:51)
at org.apache.lucene.util.AbstractBeforeAfterRule$1.evaluate(AbstractBeforeAfterRule.java:46)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.SystemPropertiesInvariantRule$1.evaluate(SystemPropertiesInvariantRule.java:59)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleThreadAndTestName$1.evaluate(TestRuleThreadAndTestName.java:49)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures.java:65)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleMarkFailure$1.evaluate(TestRuleMarkFailure.java:48)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$StatementRunner.run(ThreadLeakControl.java:367)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl.forkTimeoutingTask(ThreadLeakControl.java:809)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$3.evaluate(ThreadLeakControl.java:460)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.runSingleTest(RandomizedRunner.java:873)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$5.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:775)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$6.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:809)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$7.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:820)
at org.apache.lucene.util.AbstractBeforeAfterRule$1.evaluate(AbstractBeforeAfterRule.java:46)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleStoreClassName$1.evaluate(TestRuleStoreClassName.java:42)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.SystemPropertiesInvariantRule$1.evaluate(SystemPropertiesInvariantRule.java:59)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule$1.evaluate(NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule.java:39)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule$1.evaluate(NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule.java:39)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleAssertionsRequired$1.evaluate(TestRuleAssertionsRequired.java:43)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleMarkFailure$1.evaluate(TestRuleMarkFailure.java:48)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures.java:65)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreTestSuites$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreTestSuites.java:55)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$StatementRunner.run(ThreadLeakControl.java:367)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Since it is a Unit Testing I have not used configuration Settings to create client.

**is there a way to recreate the client Object with same configuration settings??**

Comment: doesn't simply calling `client()` and assigning it to `csvImporter.client` work? The framework should create a client for the same `cluster`. Now the problem is you have only one node which you are closing hence the `[]` in the error message.

Comment: In [elasticsearch code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1.7/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/search/query/SearchQueryTests.java) just client() has been used.  Sometimes it works fine without exception. For unit testing is it possible to create the client with the settings object ??. So that i can recreate the object with the same settings

Comment: yes you can have a race condition between test code and node shutdown. Can you just try adding `csvImporter.client =  client();` after `csvImporter.importData();`?

Comment: Yes.. added that.. I have been running 4 test cases. If i run each test case individually then everything works fine. But if i run all the 4 test cases, getting inconsistent result. Sometimes all the 4 test cases are getting passed and sometimes anyone of those 4 test cases is getting failed.

Comment: are they failing with the above exception still (no nodes) or a new one?

Comment: yes, same Exception :                      org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
 at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([54BBC711F86E0F5C:4B6187D66BEB7B58]:0)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:305)
 at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:200)

Comment: It works fine and consistent If I comment the client.close() statement. shouldn't the client be closed??

Comment: you should close the client on application shutdown, otherwise having one shared client, instead of creating a client per request, is usually a good idea. I'm not sure how that testing library works so you still might get race conditions between `close()` and `client()`